# Find available "number" in a 2d array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have this problem that I need to solve in the most effecient way. 
I have a 2d array that contains the following: 
Everything that is a 1 is a "wall" which means you cannot go through it. 2 is the entrance where you "enter" the array or map if you like. 3 are the things we need to find. Here is an example of a map:

```
1111111
1  3131
2 11111
1    31
1111111
```

This could be an example of an array that i need to look in. As you can see there is a 3 that is "unreachable, since it's surrounded by a wall "1". Which means that there are two available numbers in this array.

First we need to find the entrance. Since the entrance can be anywhere I need to search the entire array. I have done the following:

```
int treasureAmount = 0;
     Point entrance = new Point(0,0);
     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < N; i++){
             if(map[i][j] == 2){
                 entrance.x =i;
                 entrance.y =j;
             }

         }
```

This takes O(n^2) time, and i don't really see another way to do this, since the entrance can be anywhere.
However i'm not really sure how to find the available numbers effectivly and fast. I thought about while searching the arrays for the entrance i will at the same time find the all the number 3 in the array even though some might not be accessible, and after that i'm not really sure how to effectivly find which are accessible.

Comment: O(n^2) (or O(mn)) is the best you can do here. The thing is whether you can do it in less operations or not...

Comment: _"First we need to find the entrance ... the entrance can be anywhere"_ is the entrance literally anywhere, or is it restricted to the "perimeter" of the array - like in the example you provide?

Comment: The entrance can be anywhere in the array. It might be in the middle or on the "edge"

Comment: A path searching algorithm would work here, to see if it can find an available path from entrance to the items you need to find.

Comment: Your inner loop uses `i++` - you probably mean `j++`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon You are correct :) I didn't notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it better that O(n^2). It will take that much time just to read the array. But then you could do a depth first search to find the reachable 3's in the array. Here is the pseudo code.

```
main()
{
    read array and mark the entrance as ent.x and ent.y and also an array threex[] and threey[] that stores all the exit position.
    boolean visited[][]; //stores whether array[i][j] is reachable or not.
    dfs(ent.x,ent.y);
    for each element in three arrays
    {
        if(visited[threex[i]][threey[i]]) print ("Reachable");
        else print("not reachable", threex[i], threey[i]);
    }
}
int dx[]={1,0,-1,0},dy[]={0,1,0,-1}; // dx[i], dy[i] tells whether to move in E,N,W,S respectively.
dfs(int x,int y)
{
    visited[x][y]=true;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)//move in all directions
    {
        int newx=x+dx[i],newy=y+dy[i];
        //check if this is within the array boundary
        if(newx>=0&&newx<N && newy>=0&&newy<N)
        if(!visited[newx][newy] && array[newx][newy]!=1) // check if the node is unvisited and that it is pemissible
             dfs(newx,newy);
    }
}
```

Since each array element is taken up not more than once in the dfs function the complexity of the code is O(n^2).

Comment: It almost works ^^ I thank you alot. In my implementation it sometimes fails at showing a path where there is none. It only happens along the edge. In my example i posted, one of the "1" along the edge would be shown as a possible place to move, even though it's not the entrance

Comment: I got it to work... i accedently switched a point which caused the entrance to be mirrored

Comment: How would you analyze the running time of this ? I guess that worst case it has to go through every single position in the array, making it n^2 time worst case?

Comment: Right.. In worst case, each element of the array (O(n^2) elements ) are taken in the dfs method. They are never repeated, because once the visited[][] is set to true, it is never set to false again. So the worst case is 4*n^2 = O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

When creating the array, you can keep a list of coordinates of that have the value of 2. You can traverse that list in O(n).

Comment: I need to find an effective way of getting the number 3. I need to assume that i'm given the complete array, and after that i need to search it somehow. I'm 100% sure that I can only find the entrance 2 with a double for loop, which will take O(n^2) time. Maybe one could use breadth first search to somehow find the available numbers?

Comment: You will need to use some kind of a flood fill algorithm, but instead of searching for values of 2 in O(n^2), you can start searching right away from the coordinates which have a value of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since both entrance  and target items can be anywhere in the array you don't have much choice, but to search everything. So, your entrance search is as efficient as it can be, and regarding the target items I recommend the [maze flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

However, the linked version of the algorithm favorizes one direction (like it is filling it with water, it floods "down"). To be as efficient as it can, you should make it expand in all directions (like you're filling it with gas), e.g.:

```
            2
      1    212
0    101  21012
      1    212
            2
```

The numbers represent the iterations of expansion. The expansion is made in four directions: left, right, up and down. When you reach the target item, you can find the shortest route simply by backtracking to the adjacent cell neighbour whose iteration index is lesser by one, until you return to the 0 iteration index - the entrance.