# Search 2d Array

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

So im writing a java program which should find the shortest way from the entrance `"2"` to one of the numbers `"3"`. It can only walk on `" "` positions. `"1"` is walls.

```
11111121 
131    1 
1 1 1111 
1 1 13 1     
1 1 11 1 
1 1    1
1      1  
11111111
```

My starting idea is to find the entrance in the 2d array. This could be done like this:

```
Point entrance = new Point(0,0);
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        if(map[i][j] == 2){
           entrance.x =i;
           entrance.y =j;
        }
   }
```

I could also find the two `"3"` and save them in points. **but** im not sure how to return the rute to the closest `"3"`. I was considering like a joystick, where I save the what direction you go, like (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT).
Then return the full list of moves from the entrance to the closests 3.
Got any suggestion or ideas how I could implement this ?

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding . A sample algorithm is provided. You can use that as a starting point.

Comment: I will look into that link. While I try figure it out

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213282/find-available-number-in-a-2d-array

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is simply a non-cannonical representation of a graph. You have each cell being a vertex in the graph and you have an edge between two neighboring cells if and only if both of them are free.

Now that you look at the problem in this way, find the entrance like you do and than do a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find the exit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a counter that will increment every time the current position is " " (walk-able)

Notation `" "` = `0` in the matrix:

```
Point entrance = new Point(0,0);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
    if(map[i][j] == 2){
       entrance.x =i;
       entrance.y =j;
    }
}

Point firstexit = new Point(0,0);
int steps = 0;
int i = entrance.x;
int j = entrance.y;
int lasti = 0;
int lastj = 0;
while(true){

    if(map[i][j] == 3){
       firstexit.x =i;
       firstexit.y =j;
       break ;
    }
    if(map[i][j] == 0){
       steps++;
    }

    // TO-DO : check if position exists
    if(map[i][j+1] == 0 && (lasti != i && lastj != j)){
       lastj = j;
       j++;
    }else if(map[i][j-1] == 0 && (lasti != i && lastj != j)){
       lastj = j;
       j--;
    }else if(map[i+1][j] == 0 && (lasti != i && lastj != j)){
       lasti = i;
       i++;
    }else if(map[i-1][j] == 0 && (lasti != i && lastj != j)){
       lasti = i;
       i--;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, I like the way you're thinking but dont you just find all the locations where there is " " aka. 0.
You should only find the amount of moves from entrance to 3.

Comment: yes ur right, i just realized this when i posted the answer :)) and now i'm thinking how to edit it.

Comment: Im doing the same. Im trying to use 'steps++;' if you move in a certain direction. Like map[i-1][j] = Left, map[i+1][j] = Right, map[i][j-1] = Up and map[i][j+1] = Down. Will fill you in if I get breaktrough :)

Comment: exactly that i did :D think-alike :)

Comment: This will not work Stephan :s 
Im pretty sure it has to be more specific.
Either go from the entrance[x][y] coords or go from the exit[x][y] is they way i believe.

Comment: I've updated the answer , i start from the entrance and "move" on the next position where i have `0` but i have to check also i do not make a loop

Comment: I modified your suggestion because you used dublicated variables "i" and "j". The problem now is your "while(1)" loop. You can't use an integer as argument in while loops so im trying to modify this part

Comment: sorry about that i meant `while(true)`

Comment: Im getting array out of bounds. :/ At a--; and b--;

Comment: yeah because i didn't checked the bounds `// TO-DO : check if position exists`

Answer (score 0):

I would try and create a graph with nodes and edges. Nodes are the junctions in the maze, and edges are the paths between junctions and entrance or exit objects. Each edge object has a 'weight'. Once you calculate the network from the double array, you can use some easy algorithm to work out the shortest route.